# C# Updating PictureBox image

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, thread-safety

I'm working on a small screen sharing project,and in the main loop(on a second thread) i read data from a connected socket,process it to a small image(kind of a block,with `X` and `Y` properties which indicate where to draw that block),and need to redraw it on the previous image-it has to update very fast(at least this is my goal).

So far i created `Graphics` from the initial image,and used the `Graphics.DrawImage` method to draw the smaller block(constantly recieved from socket),on the current image.

This is how it looks like:

```
      private void MainScreenThread()
    {
        ReadData();
        initial = bufferToJpeg();
        while (true)
        {
            int pos = ReadData();
            x = BlockX();
            y = BlockY();
            Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg();
            Draw(block,new Point(x,y));
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Refresh()));         
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        lock (initial)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, 0, 0);
        }
    }
```

I did some benchmarking,and i've seen that the `DrawImage` method works quite slow.

An average time to draw a 800X500 image was **~520ms~**.

I decided to implement a faster method myself,using unsafe pointer for faster access.

```
 private  unsafe void Draw(Bitmap bmp2, Point point)
    {
        lock (initial)
        {
            BitmapData bmData = initial.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, initial.Width, initial.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, initial.PixelFormat);
            BitmapData bmData2 = bmp2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp2.Width, bmp2.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bmp2.PixelFormat);
            IntPtr scan0 = bmData.Scan0;
            IntPtr scan02 = bmData2.Scan0;
            int stride = bmData.Stride;
            int stride2 = bmData2.Stride;
            int Width = bmp2.Width;
            int Height = bmp2.Height;
            int X = point.X;
            int Y = point.Y;

            for (int y = 0; y < Height; y++)
            {
                byte* p = (byte*)scan0.ToPointer();
                p += (Y + y) * stride + X * 4;//setting pointer according the smaller bitmap bounds.
                byte* p2 = (byte*)scan02.ToPointer();
                p2 += stride2 * y;

                for (int x = 0; x < Width; x++)
                {
                    p[0] = p2[0];//B
                    p[1] = p2[1];//G
                    p[2] = p2[2];//R
                    p += 4;//advance pointer +4
                    p2 += 4;//advance pointer +4
                }

            }
            initial.UnlockBits(bmData);
            bmp2.UnlockBits(bmData2);
        }
    }
```

And now the call looks like this:

```
   while (true)
        {
            int pos = ReadData();
             x = BlockX();
            y = BlockY();
            Bitmap block = bufferToJpeg();
           Draw(block,new Point(x,y));
            this.Invoke(new Action(() => pictureBox1.Refresh()));         
        }
```

But i keep getting an

> Object is currently in use elsewhere

When i lock the initial image..in this line

```
 BitmapData bmData = initial.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, initial.Width, initial.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, initial.PixelFormat);
```

I'm not sure why this happening..i do not access `initial` from any other source...

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: When locking, can you use this statement before: `lock(initial)` and then `lock(bmp2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing `initial` from another source:  Namely the main GUI thread responsible for painting the pictureBox because of your `pictureBox1.Image = initial`

My advice.  get rid of the `pictureBox1.Image = initial` bit, and add an OnPaint handler to the pictureBox to draw the image manually.  Then add some simple locking code around the use of the resource, for instance in your background thread, something like:

```
lock (initial)
{
    BitmapData bmData = initial.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, initial.Width, initial.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, initial.PixelFormat);
    // ....
    initial.UnlockBits(bmData);
}
```

And then in your OnPaint handler, do something like:

```
lock (initial)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, 0, 0);
}
```

This will prevent the two threads from colliding when attempt to access the same resource.

Comment: thanks you first of all for you answer.
I've updated the code according to your suggestion,but now i get a `Object cannot be null` exception on the paint event(when i lock th initial image). in this line 
`lock (initial)`.see the updated question please.

Comment: oh! i fixed it.. initial was really null at the beggining haha. one more thing,because this kiind or program really demands efficiecy,is that the fastest way to draw it again in the picturebox? assisgning it's value like `PictureBox1.Image=initial;` wont be faster?

Comment: Someone still needs to draw the image, there's not really a reason to think drawing it in one place will be dramatically faster than another.  Indeed, when you set the `image` property, it still gets drawn via a `Graphics.DrawImage` call, as you can see in the [source to PictureBox](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/PictureBox.cs,1320).

Comment: alright. awesome :).
one last think-evethough the picturebox is in strech mode it still doesnt look like this...any chance to change it via the `Paint` event?before i used your solution it displayed the image in strech mode indeed :)

Comment: Add a rectangle to the `DrawImage` call, like `e.Graphics.DrawImage(initial, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle);` to stretch the image.

Comment: works very slow now i'll leave it to  be fixed size  haha.thanks.